# How to automatically color cells of the current month in calendar

Tags: excel, vba, date, calendar

i have a calendar in Excel which continues until July 2020. What i would like to have in my worksheet is an automatic coloration of all cells of the "current month" every time i open the workbook.

I did already the "current day auto-coloration"
This is the code :

```
Public Sub FormattaCalendario()

  Dim LColCount As Long
  Dim cell As Variant

  ultimoGiorno = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)
  primoGiorno = ultimoGiorno - Day(ultimoGiorno) + 1

  LColCount = Cells(TrovaInizioProgetti(activeCell) - 1, 
  Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  For Each cell In Range(Cells(TrovaInizioProgetti(activeCell) - 1, 11), 
  Cells(TrovaInizioProgetti(activeCell) - 1, LColCount))

    If cell.Value = Date Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 91)
    End If

    If CDate(cell.Value) <> Date Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 0)
    End If

  Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are only taking the day you are in, instead you need to use `If Month(cell) = Month(Date) then` that way you pick up the month.

Comment: Something like :

    `If cell.Value = Month(Date) Then
      cell.Interior.Color = 'Color
    End If`

Comment: No, because `cell.value` is the date, not  the month... you need to use the `Month()` for both comparisions. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replacement should work for what you're requesting:

```
If Month(CDate(cell.Value)) = Month(Date) Then
  cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 91)
Else
  cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 0)
End If
```

Note that you don't need two separate `IF` statements for this.

Comment: Okay, it worked, thanks a lot.
One last question, to color also the current day?

Comment: @Lomoo put the one you had with `If` and checking the month a `ElseIf`

Comment: Ok, i forgot also an option to color saturdays and sundays, is that possible?

Comment: Which one overrides, today or saturday and sunday?

Comment: All three of them.

Comment: So if today is saturday, which colour needs to be shown? Because I believe you want today in a colour, saturdays and sundays in a different colour and the rest of the month in a different colour. So which one is it?

Comment: Anyhow, thinking that the If statement goes line by line and will stop when the comparision is true, what you need to know is that `Format(cell, "dddd") = "Saturday"` or sunday will do the trick, now use it with your logic.

Comment: Ok sorry, i didn't understand. 
If today is saturday then color as a today cell, so yellow.
If today isn't Saturday/Sunday, color in RGB(170,170,170)

Comment: @Damian I didn't understand this logic well :( 
What should i do?

Comment: `If Format(cell, "dddd") = "Saturday" or Format(cell, "dddd") = "Sunday" Then`

Comment: And those "dddd"  what do they mean?

Comment: @Lomoo go to Excel and cell formating, you can toy there and try what it does. Supose you have 25/09/2019, "dd" = 25, "ddd" = short name for the day, "dddd" = full name of the day. Same with month "mm", "mmm", "mmmm"  you can format a date however you need

Answer (score 4):

This can be done a lot easier with conditional formatting. Apply this formula to the range where your dates are in:

```
=MONTH(A1)=MONTH(NOW())
```

This will highlight every cell within that range which has a date within the current month. Make sure to change "A1" to the first cell within that range. Or if you want the entire row highlighted, enter `$*Column*1` instead, where `*Column*` is the column your dates are in. Then apply to your entire sheet.

**EDIT** As I still believe in this answer more than the VBA option I'll also answer the questions in the comments on that answer:

Todays date can be highlighted with the formula:

```
=A1=TODAY()
```

**EDIT 2**
[After some trouble and learning on my part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096027/workday-returns-unexpected-value-on-blank-cells?noredirect=1#comment102584602_58096027) the best formula to highlight the weekend days is as so:

```
=IF(CELL("format",A1)="D1",WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5,FALSE)
```

With thanks to @shrivallabha.redij and @Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: This is totally unnecessary  Plutian, you have the `Month()` which is much shorter and clean.

Comment: That is indeed a cleaner way to do it, and gives the same result. I'll update my answer. I forgot about the `Month()` since I was more concerned about getting my point across about doing this with conditional formatting.

Comment: Whilst CF is volatile, I think I would still prefer it over a more static cell color through VBA. =)

Comment: @JvdV agreed, if anything it should be considerably faster, negating the need to trigger a macro on every workbook open or change.