# WORKDAY() returns unexpected value on blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to set up conditional formatting to highlight when a date is in the weekend with this formula:

```
=WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5
```

This works fine when applied to a range only containing dates. However when there is any blanks or numeric values these also get formatted. I've tested and the formula `=WEEKDAY(A1)` where A1 is blank returns 6, implying it is a Saturday.

Question 1:
Does anyone know why this is?

Question 2:
How do I get around this, and leave blank cells unformatted? I've considered `ISNUMBER` and `ISBLANK` which would work for blanks, but not for numeric values within the range.

Comment: On a limited Date formatting styles you can use function `CELL` e.g. `=CELL("format",A1)` will return `D4` for cell formatted as "m/d/yyyy".

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I've applied this as `=IF(CELL("format",A1)="D1",WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5,FALSE)` in my conditional formatting, and it works like a charm. If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it, if not I'll accept @Foxfire And Burns And Burns answer.

Comment: instead of =WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5 you can write =AND(WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5, A1<>"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect the cell formatted as Date for limited number of date styles you can use `CELL` function:

```
=CELL("format",A1)
```

e.g. for date format m/d/yyyy it will return "D4" which can be used for testing the value being entered.

Please refer the answer provided by Foxfire and Burns and Burns for the other query.

Answer (score 3):

A blank value equals to 0.

Dates in Excel work as numbers. First day Excel can recognize is number 1, which equals to 1st January 1900 (Sunday), number 2 means 2nd January 1900, and so on. Actually today is 25th september 2019, which numeric value is 43733.

So because 1 it's Sunday, 0 it's Saturday (it would be 0 JAnuary 1900, but that's not posible)

That explains the *Does anyone know why this is?*

About second question, because dates are also numeric values, you'll need to figure out how to check them. Maybe if the dates are in a specific range, you can check first if that number is between those values.

To see the numeric value of a date, just type any date in a cell, and change format to *General* or *Numeric*

Comment: On a limited Date formatting styles you can use function CELL e.g. =CELL("format",A1) will return D4 for cell formatted as "m/d/yyyy".

Comment: This does indeed answer my first question. I know dates are stored as numerics, but couldn't figure out why a blank would return a Saturday. But if date 0, even though non-existent, would be a Saturday, that explains sufficiently why excel recognizes is as such.